# How to export/import an array in Julia?

Tags: arrays, julia

I want to move an array from my laptop (Julia 1.3.1) to my desktop PC (Julia 1.6.2).
I make an array in Julia 1.3.1 as follows.

```
using LinearAlgebra

H = ... #give a matrix H
eigen,vector = eigen(H)
```

Then, I'd like to move "vector" to Julia 1.6.2.

How do you do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is by using `DelimitedFiles`:

```
julia> v = [1.0,2.0,3.0]

julia> using DelimitedFiles
                           
julia> writedlm("f.txt", v)
                           

julia> readdlm("f.txt")
3×1 Matrix{Float64}:
 1.0
 2.0
 3.0

julia> vec(readdlm("f.txt"))
3-element Vector{Float64}:
 1.0
 2.0
 3.0
```

Note that `DelmitedFiles` works with matrices so the last example shows what to do if you rather store a vector.

#### Edit following Bogumil's comment

When you have  a `Matrix` of `Complex` numbers you need to provide the output type for `readdlm`:

```
julia> v = Complex.(rand(2,3), rand(2,3))
2×3 Matrix{ComplexF64}:
 0.282157+0.540556im  0.757765+0.103518im  0.979935+0.212347im
 0.557499+0.934859im  0.604032+0.338489im  0.431962+0.945946im

julia> writedlm("f.txt", v)

julia> readdlm("f.txt",'\t',Complex{Float64})
2×3 Matrix{ComplexF64}:
 0.282157+0.540556im  0.757765+0.103518im  0.979935+0.212347im
 0.557499+0.934859im  0.604032+0.338489im  0.431962+0.945946im

julia> readdlm("f.txt",'\t',Complex{Float64}) == v
true
```

Another way is to use a binary format. For long term in-between version serialization `BSON` (binary json) could be a good option:

```
julia> using BSON

julia> BSON.bson("v.bson", v = v)

julia> v2 = BSON.load("v.bson")[:v]
2×3 Matrix{ComplexF64}:
 0.282157+0.540556im  0.757765+0.103518im  0.979935+0.212347im
 0.557499+0.934859im  0.604032+0.338489im  0.431962+0.945946im
```

Comment: `eigen` produces a matrix as its second return value. Also typically it is a matrix of complex numbers. `readdlm` will not handle this correctly. I think it is better to recommend a binary format. Between Julia 1.3 and 1.6 even `serialize` and `deserialize` should work fine.

Comment: Thanks, both of you! That was very helpful.